# Upload Video with the Imgur RapidAPI

Tags: imgur

So I know this question has been asked here before but not specifically with RapidAPI. Anyways, the RapidAPI page forwards the documentation to https://api.imgur.com/
which further forwards to https://apidocs.imgur.com/
where finally we can find the api endpoint https://api.imgur.com/3/upload

[image]

now this endpoint is not compatible with the rapid api because there is simply no /3/upload endpoint on rapidapi. although it is written in the documentation that `/3/upload` is the same as `/3/image` which would make  https://api.imgur.com/3/upload into https://imgur-apiv3.p.rapidapi.com/3/image. Problem here is that when i make a request to this endpoint with a video instead of an image in the payload i get this response json:

```
{'data': {'error': 'Could not process upload!', 'request': '/3/image', 'method': 'POST'}, 'success': False, 'status': 500}
```

Which basically tells me that it cannot parse the file format because when uploading any type of image it works. So what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```py
import requests

url = "https://api.imgur.com/3/upload"

payload = {'album': 'ALBUMID',
'type': 'file',
'disable_audio': '0'}
files = [
  ('video', open('/path/to/Video.mp4','rb'))
]
headers = {
  'Authorization': 'Bearer BEARERTOKENHERE'
}

response = requests.request("POST", url, headers=headers, data = payload, files = files)

print(response.text.encode('utf8'))
```

Comment: I am spesifically asking about the rapidapi endpoint, read the question again or remove your answer, this is misleading.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can only upload videos via the API anonymously. I think that's probably why rapidapi doesn't support it

Comment: ok but what are the implications then? is there rate limiting and are the uploads automatically made public or? Also what is the point of the authorization header then? The problem is that I am using the API commercially and the documentation clearly states that i must explicitly only use the RapidAPI endpoints in that case.

Comment: good question - i guess the bearer isn't even necessary. I found that this video endpoint was super inconsistent, and IIRC I could only ever get it to upload anonymously. I ended up abandoning the project. The video would be there, but couldn't be added to an account or album even if you specified it in the payload. Imgur documentation really blows.

Comment: Ok, I figured something out, basically if you take the answer you gave and modify it and use it with rapidapi you can actually get it to upload video and tied to an account. But the problem now is that response json gives something weird called a 'ticket'. And it does not give the upload link. Although it is clearly saved to my account and privately too. Can you get in contact with me so we can solve this?

Comment: Can you upvote this question because this is a legitimate problem with the api.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I can understand their API /3/upload is for video & image but requires a token to use.

/3/image is for images only and should be used for uploading anonymous images with no user authentication.

But I am not 100% sure about that since I was not able to get a token to upload to /upload myself. (since I wanted to upload to my account in a 2 legged OAuth which looks like is not supported?)

So what you would need to do is to call /auth to get your token, exchange this token for a BEARER TOKEN to use the /upload path.

Hope this explains it a bit.

Comment: You don't understand, RapidAPI does not have the /3/upload endpoint at all. There is only /3/image. /3/image actually accepts video which i recently discovered. Although it does not return the link to the uploaded content so that is rather weird.

Comment: Regardless can you upvote this issue, this is a legitimate problem with the api.